# What are coupling orders combinations and QED-QCD interference term s

Tags: particle-physics

I'm studying MadGraph, and there's a command '^' I don't quite understand what it actually does. The help says that:

Desired coupling orders combination can be specified directly for the squared matrix element by appending '^2' to the coupling name. For example, 'p p > j j QED^2==2 QCD^==2' selects the QED-QCD interference terms only. The other two operators '<=' and '>' are supported. Finally, a negative value COUP^2==-I refers to the N^(-I+1)LO term in the expansion of the COUP order.

But I still don't understand because I don't know what are coupling orders combinations and QED-QCD interference terms, and why do we need them in our simulations.

Is there anyone whose's familiar with MG5? Thanks!